# Target=_blank don't work in mozilla and IE

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form for submitting and posting result in new tab , my code working fine in Chrome, but when i open my page in Mozilla or IE , it doesn't work , and new tab will not Open.

all i want is to open form submitting in new tab , in common browsers (mozilla,chrome,IE)

Here is my code:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action method="post" target="_blank" id="test1">
<input type="text" name="txtUserPrice" id="txtUserPrice" />
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmitForm" value="Buy" />
</form>
```

i think my problem come from `target="_blank"` , Because in chrome, it open new tab. But other browsers (Mozilla and IE) doesn't.

How can i fix this?

One more question:

This problem , cause for different browser rendering or code parsing?

Comment: @DenysSéguret , yeah you right , i check it on own page , but need it to open in new tab.after submit this form i change form to another , because of that i need to open this form in new tab

Answer (score 1):

This code perfectly working on my mozilla & IE. I think clients need to update the browsers ...

Comment: All browsers is up to date- mozilla (46.0.1), IE(11.0.9)

Answer (score 1):

**this is a Known Bug Microsoft Internet Explorer**

Some versions of MSIE have a bug which renders anchors using "_blank" inoperative. See "Open In New Window" Does Not Work in Internet Explorer for the patch.

Read more at:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/intermittent-problems-with-targetblank-in-ie-9/c7e937be-7400-41e9-bf03-14474fbc1832?auth=1

Comment: tnx for Answer , but, what about mozilla? do you have any idea ?

Comment: All browsers is up to date- mozilla (46.0.1), IE(11.0.9)

Comment: another check...please disable your popup blocker, form browser settings and third party popup blocker if installed https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting

Comment: I disable it , but still have problem. it think this compel me to use only with chrome :)

Comment: consider that this problem is yours and not happens to your users because the code you post here is totally right

Answer (score 0):

Please check by replacing `_blank` with `blank`

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action method="post" target="blank" id="test1">
```

Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/mump316n/2/)

Comment: Tnx for your reply, but Still have problem!

Answer (score 0):

try replace `target` to `onclick`

```
onclick="window.open('example.php', 'newwindow', 'width=800, height=600'); return false;"
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, but Still Have problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try, adding `formtarget` attribute to submit button :

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action method="post" target="_blank" id="test1">
    <input type="text" name="txtUserPrice" id="txtUserPrice" />
    <input type="submit" formtarget="_blank" name="btnSubmitForm" value="Buy" />
</form>
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, but still have problem.